# Responsive expendable items with FlexBox getting cuttoff

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a row of items that can expand. Currently I almost have what I need, in terms of behaviour everything works except:

1. On Desktop the items are cuttoff and cannot be seen fully.
2. On Mobile half the items are missing and you cannot scroll to them.

[Here is how it looks like (imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJGYh.jpg)

Now this is 100% due to my Flex setup and how I handle it, but I only recently got a hang of it and now I have to learn the interactions between all of the properties. So if you can provide an explanation alongside the answer I'd greatly appreciate it!

This is my Card that contains these items (it's written in kotlin but it should be understandable)

```
  val x = { props ->
             // this is the Card
            return@fc div("w-full flex flex-col items-center shadow-lg p-4 rounded-lg lg:shadow-none") {

                // This is the container holding the items
                div("flex w-full gap-3 overflow-x-auto items-start justify-center my-5 snap-x p-2") {
                    model.content.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                        ModeratedContentItem {

                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

And these are the items:

```
return@fc div("w-full shadow-md rounded-md " +
            "items-center max-w-sm flex-initial lg:shrink-0 snap-center " + if(expanded) " flex-none " else " shrink ") {
 ...........
```

The idea is, on desktop they would be as big as possible, then when the screen is smaller they would shrink slowly. But when expanded they would take up as much space as possible again.

From my studies on how FlexBox works, this in theory should work, I am unable to understand why the scrolling is messed up when playing with shrinking and flex.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, adding Justify Content Center to the container holding the items causes most of the issues.

I am trying to have the items start from the center (when there are only 1 or 2 items I want them to be centered) and I use items-start so that when the items are expanded they don't influence the other items and all stay attached to the top.

EDIT: [Here's a codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-vrddz?file=/postcss.config.js), it's not working for mobile but showcases the issue for desktop

As you can see, when there are multiple items it streches the parent, if you expand 1 item the parent will go into the correct size, not sure why is this happening like this

Answer (score 0):

[It seems this was caused by a bug](https://bhch.github.io/posts/2021/04/centring-flex-items-and-allowing-overflow-scroll/), for god's sake, implementing the solution from the article seems to have fixed the issue